# What is causing the replacement of tabs with spaces in schema.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, schema, database-migration, ruby-on-rails-5.1

After a few migrations the schema.rb file changed a lot - all the tabulations where replaced with spaces. What is causing this behaviour? Didn't remember doing anything to achieve such outcome. 
[image: tabulations]
VS

[image: spaces]

Comment: What text editor are you using? Sublime has options and will overwrite spaces with tabs and visa versa depending on your settings

Comment: @Mark - the problem was indeed editor configuration (Rubymine to be exact) - if you could post it as an answer, then I can mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What text editor are you using? Sublime has options and will overwrite spaces with tabs and visa versa depending on your settings